# GWT SerializationException when passing Serializable objects as parameter

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

I get `SerializationException` when passing  `ArrayList<MyObject>` as parameter to RPC servlet method. Class `MyObject` consist only 2 fields with types `String` and `Serializable`. Into `Serializable` field I pass values as `Boolean`(`checkBox.getValue`), `String(textBox.getValue)` and `Date(dateBox.getValue)`. So inside `Serializable` field I  have always types which are 100% can be serialized. Why this exception can be rised?

Thanks.

Comment: What exception? Post the complete message and stack trace. It almost certainly contains the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use Serializable as a type for GWT RPC, likewise I couldn't use Object instances. GWT can't handle it properly. Also your object which you want to serialize with RPC should have default constructor, even if its empty. Paste your code and exception message in the question.

Comment: `should have default constructor` - I forget doing that. Big thanks!